# Pipe problem? cat | cat | ls doesn't work in my minishell

Tags: c, process, pipe, signals

me and a friend are working on creating a minishell. We ran into some issues on the `cat | cat | ls part`  and couldn't figure out what the cause is. Instead of displaying the output of ls right after we press enter, it only does it after we press ctrl-c (in our case is to display a new line)

```
int ft_ex(char **argv, char **envp, int i, t_node *env_list)
{   
    int pid;
    int res;

    pid = fork();
    if (!pid)
    {
        argv[i] = 0;
        if (execve(*argv, envp, ft_getenv(env_list)) == -1)
        {
            printf("Error: %s command not found\n", *envp);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        while (waitpid(pid, &res, WNOHANG) == 0)
            continue ;
        if (WIFEXITED(res))
            return (g_exit_num = WEXITSTATUS(res));
        else
            return (1);
    }
    return (0);

int create_pipe(t_mini *mini)
{
    int     fd[2];
    int     status;

    status = pipe(fd);
    if (status < 0)
    {
        mini->pipe_read = -1;
        mini->pipe_write = -1;
        return (0);
    }
    mini->pipe_read = fd[0];
    mini->pipe_write = fd[1];
    return (1);
}

void    for_heredoc(t_mini *mini, t_token *tok)
{
    mini->heredoc = 1;
    tok = tok->next;
    tok->type = ARG;
    here_doc_input(mini, tok, 0);
}

void    call_pipe_redirect(t_mini *mini, t_token *command, t_token *tok)
{
    if (!command)
        return ;
    if (tok && tok->type == PIPE)
    {
        create_pipe(mini);
        tok = tok->next;
    }
    else if (tok && tok->type == HEREDOC)
    {
        for_heredoc(mini, tok);
    }
    else if (tok && (tok->type == TRUNC || tok ->type == APPEND))
    {
        tok = tok->next;
        tok->type = ARG;
        redirect_output(mini, tok, tok->prev->type);
    }
    else if (tok && (tok->type == INPUT))
    {
        tok = tok->next;
        tok->type = ARG;
        redirect_input(mini, tok);
    }
}
}
```

we tried playing around with this part but altho it displays the output for ls right after, it causes issues when we want to continue running commands.

```
while (waitpid(pid, &res, WNOHANG) == 0)
            continue ;
```

Comment: That's the correct behavior.  Have you tried the same thing in bash?

Comment: yepp in bash it gives back the output of ls and a newline once i press enter. But in my minishell, it gives only a newline when i press enter and the output of ls only comes out after i press ctrl-c